# Convert string with commas into integer in Freemarker

Tags: string, integer, freemarker

I have a string with commas in between. How should I convert this string into an integer. I tried using

```
x?number
```

but that gives me the following error

```
Exceptionfreemarker.core.NonNumericalException
```

e.g. The string is "453,000". I need to convert this to 453000.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no function built in for parsing numbers with national formats. `?number` only deals with computer format, because when numbers are transferred as strings (which should be already rare), that's what used to be used. So in principle `x` should be already a number when it gets to FreeMarker, or at least it should use computer format. If that's not possible, you will need a custom function (or method) for that.