# FreeMarker convert string with commas to number

Tags: freemarker

I need to convert a locale specific string value having either commas or dot in between to indicate thousands separator, to a number in FreeMarker by removing the decimal places. For example: `13,456.79` to `13,456` OR `23.675,98` to `23.675`

Using `?number` throws exception saying this string can't be converted to a number. I see a similar question here:
[Convert string with commas into integer in Freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838953/convert-string-with-commas-into-integer-in-freemarker) but no solution exist. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Seems wrong design decision in fundaments. Use correct model. Template should not correct problems in data (in this context: number should be true numeric type)

Comment: @Jacek Cz I agree absolutely. And that design correction is next on my implementation list as similar issues currently exist for many more cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the limitations like locale specific numbers where decimal and thousands separator characters can either be a dot or a comma, and since I only needed to display the value and not do any numeric calculations based on the number value, I resolved this by simply ignoring the last 3 characters of the string using `substring`. This will remove the decimal separator and 2 decimal places (assumption being that there are always 2 decimal places).

Answer (score 4):

I would parse the variable as Integer before (in the Controller/Business layer) exposing it to the template (and react in case of problems with the format).

In my opinion templates should handle nothing more than the presentation of (valid) data.

## Alternately...

You can try to transform the string...

```
<#function string_to_int s >
    <#local a = s?replace(",", "") >
    <#return a?keep_before_last(".") />
</#function>
```

> ${string_to_int("13,456.79")}

will output

> 13456

Comment: Agree, but I have no control over that. Would need a solution in ftl itself.

Comment: the comma for the thousands separator should be kept intact.. also thinking about the locales where decimal point is the thousands separator and comma for the fraction part this will not work eg. 12.234,90 ... is there a more generic solution ?

Comment: OK, these are details, you can refine and improve the `#function` to suit your needs

Comment: Note that as `?stuff`-s can be chained, you don't need that `local`; you can just write `<#return s?replace(",", "")?keep_before_last(".")>`.

Comment: @shweta: If you don't even know the locale, then it's inherently an impossible task. Because, what does `1,005` mean? Depending on the locale, it can be either one-thousand and five, or one and five thousandth.